# CGPDFDocument and voiceover

Tags: ios, pdf, accessibility, voiceover

I have a PDF rendering app that loads PDF content from a URL (CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL).  The PDF loads fine, and I can display on screen no problem.  These PDF also contain text for searching.  I'm trying to make this comtent visible to the VoiceOver API.  I've never worked with this frameowrk before.

Anyone have any hints or links that can help me get started?

Comment: I am not intimately familiar with VO, so my gut check is to ask if the PDF is tagged, what pdf viewer are you using and if you researched VO + [reader name] compatibility?

Comment: Native ios Viewer.  The PDFs that we are using are read by iBooks just fine, so it's not the PDF.  I need to unwind the Accessibility framework. I'm making very small progress, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the text from the particular PDF page, you can set the `accessibilityValue` of the view you are using to display the page to the text value. This will then read the contents out.

If for some reason your PDF view is not accessible to voiceover, you can use an overlay view, and update its accessibility value as you change pages.